# Resteasy - import javax.ws.rs.Consumes cannot be resolved

Tags: java, rest, resteasy

Hi I am working with a rest api using Resteasy, simple printMessage samples work however I am getting error with this code:

```
@Consumes("application/json")
```

> Error:
>
> import javax.ws.rs.Consumes cannot be resolved

I have included all jar in the lib folder of the Resteasy zip distribution file.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may have copied your resteasy files to the META-INF directory which is incorrect. Please ensure that you have copied the resteasy files located in the lib directory to the WEB-INF lib directory of your project.